# Ms access select statement not retrieving

Tags: ms-access

i have a select statement below, but its not correctly retrieving what i want and throwing an error, help am new to ms access

SELECT order_id, ord_amount, order_date, ord_num
FROM orders
WHERE agent_code=B5458

Answer (score 0):

Your code is *text*, so:

```
SELECT order_id, ord_amount, order_date, ord_num FROM orders WHERE agent_code='B5458'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query, the error message is due to you not ending the select statement with `;`  also the where condition should have `''`.

So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT order_id, ord_amount, order_date, ord_num
FROM orders 
WHERE agent_code='B5458';
```

Try it, it should work.

Comment: In Access, the semi-colon is optional within SQL statements. It is good practice to use it though.